# Authentication with AsyncStorage

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I am using JWT for authentication in my RN App. To store the response data I am using `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` package.

Here is the Login onPress function:

```
  const loginUser = async (username, password) => {
    handleMessage(null);
    axios
      .post('APIendpoint', {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        const saveData = async () => {
          try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('user_email', response.data.user_email);
            console.log('Data saved', response.data.token);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        };
        if (!response.data.token) {
          handleMessage('error');
        } else {
          navigation.navigate('Home');
          saveData();
        }
        setSubmitting(false);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setSubmitting(false);
        handleMessage('Check your credentials and try again');
      });
  };
```

After pressing LOGIN button I do get the "Data saved" message in console - so that is successful.

Then I am trying to get the data for my initialRoute

```
const [auth, isAuth] = useState(null);
  const getAuth = async () => {
    try {
      const authToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
      if (authToken !== null) {
        isAuth(authToken);
        console.log('isauth', auth);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Failed to fetch the data from storage');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getAuth();
  }, []);
```

Here I am using the data from storage

```
initialRouteName={auth !== null ? 'Home' : 'Login'}
```

And then when logging out I just use function with `AsyncStorage.clear()`

The Issue is that my App does NOT remember the data saved in storage after closing/refreshing the app and therefore it always redirect me to Login screen after closing the app instead of to Home screen.

Is this the right approach to use? Since AsyncStorage should remember data based on my knowledge until they are destroyed (logout - clear function)

Comment: Share full share code with https://codesandbox.io/ so any body can understand your code and give you solution

Answer (score 0):

First, put your `saveData` inside the if that check if the token exists. Than I think initialRouteName does not work with dynamic parameters. Try to do Something like this instead:

```
<App>
  {auth !== null ? <Home /> : <Login />
</App>
```